# Make action optional for resource details page

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Let's say I have action "Ban" for `Product` resource and `Product` model has `is_banned` field. There is no need to show "Ban" action on details page of `Product` that is already banned (`is_banned=1`).

Laravel Nova documentation provides example of hiding actions based on whether or not admin is authorized to perform it:

```php
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        (new Actions\EmailAccountProfile)->canSee(function ($request) {
            return $request->user()->can(
                'emailAnyAccountProfile', User::class
            );
        }),
    ];
}
```

But it doesn't cover how can I get current resource's model instance in the closure I provide for `canSee` resolution when this method is called in the context of a single resource (on it's details page).

`actions()` method is where we register available actions and in my case belongs to `Product` Nova resource class, but it doesn't have access to Eloquent model's context neither.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some debugging I found out that resource's `actions()` method receives `Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest` instance that has `findModelOrFail()` method and for a single resource (for example, when viewing resource's details page) request also gets `resourceId` parameter.

So based on `resourceId` presence in the request I could now determine whether or not I am in the context of single resource operation. Then I would fetch resource's model with this id and check it's `is_banned` attribute to resolve available actions for resource.

My actions resolution logic ended up being:

```php
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->resourceId !== null) {
        $product = $request->findModelOrFail($request->resourceId);

        if ($product->is_banned) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    return [new Actions\BanProduct];
}
```

Note that `findModelOrFail()` method can be called without `$resourceId` argument and will automatically get `resourceId` value from the request in such scenario, but code's intent is clearer when specifying it directly.